# How to access multiple custom cells with didSelectRowAt

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to access the textView in my 2 custom cells but I am not sure how to approach it. I know that the following works for 1 type of custom cell

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = try tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell1") as! ImageNotesCell
        cell.notes.isEditable = true
    }
```

But I don't know how to add the selection for my other custom cell with the custom class called `NotesCell` Is there a way to have both cells inside `didSelectRowAt` so I can access their respective `UITextView` or there is no way.

Edit: for the app I'm creating, the cells types could be one of the two in no particular order

Comment: You don't access the text view from the cell. You access the text from your data model.

Comment: @rmaddy If you can explain that would be great for someone learning iOS development. Also the bigger problem to this question is me trying to record changes to those text views so I can update a database I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access cells in `didSelectRowAt` you can do this:

```
let indexPath1 = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
let cell1 = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath1) as! ImageNotesCell

let indexPath2 = IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)
let cell2 = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath2) as! ImageNotesCell
```

If you want to check which type the cell is you can do this:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
if cell is ImageNotesCell {
    print("ImageNotesCell")
} else if cell is NotesCell {
    print("NotesCell")
}
```

**But** if you´re out for the values inside the cells, then you should get these from your model array that is populating the `tableView` instead.

Comment: I'm actually trying to keep track of modified values of the cell for what I am doing and this helps me out a ton. Thanks!